# Using Requests + BeautifulSoup to Scrape Reddit

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-requests, lxml

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import lxml

url = 'http://www.reddit.com/r/JuJutsuKaisen/'
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/601.3.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0.2 Safari/601.3.9'}
r = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
print('URL: ', r.url)
print('Status code: ', r.status_code)
print('HTTP header: ', r.headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')


def parsecomments(u):
    #print(u)
    h = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/601.3.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0.2 Safari/601.3.9'}
    c = requests.get(u, h=h)
    print('URL: ', c.u)
    s = BeautifulSoup(c.text, 'lxml')
    for i in s.select('.Post'):
        try:
            print('addd',i.select('_eYtD2XCVieq6emjKBH3m')[0].get_text())
            return i.select('_eYtD2XCVieq6emjKBH3m')[0].get_text()

        except Exception as e:
            # raise e
            print('')

for item in soup.select('.Post'):
    try:
        print('----------------------------------------')
        #Number of likes
        print(item.select('._1rZYMD_4xY3gRcSS3p8ODO')[0].get_text())
        #Title
        print(item.select('._eYtD2XCVieq6emjKBH3m')[0].get_text())
        # of Comments
        print(item.select('.FHCV02u6Cp2zYL0fhQPsO')[0].get_text())
        #Post Link
        print(item.select('._2INHSNB8V5eaWp4P0rY_mE a[href]')[0]['href'])
        #Comments
        parsecomments( 'http://www.reddit.com/'+item.select('._2INHSNB8V5eaWp4P0rY_mE a[href]')[0]['href'])
    except Exception as e:
        # raise e
        print('')
```

So I am trying to use Requests+BeasutifulSoup+XML in order to scrape a subreddit. I have 2 issues.

The first is that when run it will only get the information for about 10ish posts on the subreddits. I was wondering if it was an error with my code or if there is a "limit" to how much the website will let me request. Additionally I was wondering if this might be an issue with the lxml library.

The second issue is that when I try to use my paresecomments function(it's job is to look at the post's comments) it does not work. I am not sure what is the issue with my code. It seems the function is run but the request for some reason isn't being made.

Comment: Have you tried using [Reddit API](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api/)? There's a [`praw`](https://github.com/praw-dev/praw) (Python Reddit API Wrapper) package for Python. Don't forget about [Reddit API access rules](https://github.com/reddit-archive/reddit/wiki/API) where you'll find a limit of 60 requests per minute (you can monitor them via appropriate request `headers` that were mentioned in the "Rules" section). There's also a bunch of [Reddit API Wrappers](https://github.com/reddit-archive/reddit/wiki/API-Wrappers).

Comment: I've heard of praw yes. While I do think it'll be more effective to use I don't want to entirely give up on using requests. I still would like to know what is wrong with using requests. I don't think I am making more than 2 requests in my code.

Comment: Reddit uses dynamic loading, I very much doubt you can use bs4 in your case. As @DimitryZub stated, Reddit API is one option or alternatively Selenium.